# How do I find the instantaneous rate of change of the volume of a cylinder as the radius varies while the surface area is held fixed.

Tags: calculus

I have a question in my Calculus 1 homework that I'm not sure where to begin with.

I need to calculate the instantaneous rate of change of the volume of a cylinder as the radius varies while the surface area is held fixed.

I know that volume $V=\pi r^2 h$ and surface area $S=2\pi rh+2\pir^2$ however I'm not sure how to relate them in an equation.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: My error in V was a typo but I don't understand why you have changed S. Surely $S=2\pi rh$ doesn't include the two ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Find $h$ from the equation of the surface:
$$
h=\frac{S}{2\pi r}-r
$$
and substitute in the volume:
$$
V=\pi r^2\left(\frac{S}{2\pi r}-r \right)
$$
This is the equation that gives the volume as a function o f $r$ for a given total surface $S$.

Comment: i thought about lateral surface

Comment: I've used the total surface... But the spirit is the same....  :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

using the former result and logarithmic derivative, we get the rate of change

$\frac{dV}{V}=\frac{dr}{r}-3\frac{dr}{r}=-2\frac{dr}{r}$

the rate of change of the volume is twice the rate of change of the radius.

Comment: Could you explain why $S=2\pi rh$ please?

Comment: sorry i made the correction